# How to create a pop-up box with two columns when hovering over a link?

Tags: html, css, popup, hover, box

Hey guys : ) I am creating a website and I would like to create a pop-up box of determined size that would display two columns when hovering over a link. In the left column an image and in the right column a text with a link. How do I do it using preferebly CSS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container:hover > .popup{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
.popup{
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.first-element{
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.second-element{
  border:1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>show pop up</span>
  <div class='popup'>
  <div class='first-element'>image element</div>
  <div class='second-element'><a href="#" >link elements</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, looks exactly how I had it in mind! The only thing is, that it is impossible to click on the text in the second element. It disappears again before the mouse hits the text. The second element is supposed to be a link. Do you have any idea how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

```css
.popUp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('popUp').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('popUp').style.display='none'">Something
</a>
<div class="popUp" id="popUp">Hello</div>
```